# No instance for (Fractional Int) arising from a use of `/'

Tags: haskell

I am new to Haskell, and I am struggling with debugging my code.
Fixing an error leads to other errors...

Here is my code.

```
import Data.Maybe

data Op = Add | Sub | Mul | Div | And | Or | Not | Eq | Less | Great
    deriving (Eq, Show)

data Exp = Literal Value
     | Primitive Op [Exp]
     | Variable String
     | If Exp Exp Exp
     | Let [(String, Exp)] Exp
    deriving (Show, Eq)

data Value = Number Int
       | Bool Bool
       | String String
    deriving (Eq, Show)

type Env = [(String, Value)]

eval :: Env -> Exp -> Value
eval e (Literal v) = v
eval e (Variable x) = fromJust (lookup x e)   --22

prim :: Op -> [Value] -> Value
prim Add [Number a, Number b] = Number (a + b)
prim And [Bool a, Bool b] = Bool (a && b)
prim Sub [Number a, Nuamber b] = Number (a - b)   -- No instance for (Fractional Int) arising from a use of `/'
prim Mul [Number a, Number b] = Number (a * b)
prim Div [Number a, Number b] = Number (a / b)
prim Or [Bool a, Bool b] = Bool (a || b)
prim Not [Bool a] = Bool (not a)
prim Eq [Number a, Number b] = Bool (a == b)
prim Eq [String a, String b] = Bool (a == b) 
prim Less [Number a, Number b] = Bool (a < b)
prim Less [String a, String b] = Bool (a < b)
prim Great [Number a, Number b] = Bool (a > b)
prim Great [String a, String b] = Bool (a > b) --37

main = do
    eval [("y", (Number 40))] (Let [("x", (Literal (Number 2)))] (prim Add [(Variable "x"), (Variable "y")])) -- Couldn't match expected type `Exp' with actual type `Value'
```

I am now getting two errors which I wrote in comments. 
If you know what's wrong with my code, please share your idea and save my time...

Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you mean `Number (div a b)` or its infix version?

Comment: There is a spelling mistake `Nuamber` instead of `Number`

Answer (score 70, accepted):

```
-- No instance for (Fractional Int) arising from a use of `/'
```

Presumably that's coming from this line rather than the one with your comment:

```
prim Div [Number a, Number b] = Number (a / b)
```

`a` and `b` are `Int`s. The division operator is `(/) :: Fractional a => a -> a -> a` (you can find that out by firing up ghci and entering `:t (/)`, or by [looking it up on Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=/)).

If you haven't seen types like `Fractional a => a -> a -> a`, you should read this in two parts:

1. The context `Fractional a`
2. The type `a -> a -> a`

This is just like a regular `a -> a -> a` type, so it takes two arguments of some type and gives you back a result of the same type. The only difference in adding the `Fractional a` context is that type used for `a` must be an instance of the `Fractional` type class; it isn't free to range over any type you like.

If you haven't learned about type classes yet don't worry. They're pretty easy to grasp, but not something you should be looking at in depth when you're just starting; you'll get to them later.

`Int` isn't a member of the `Fractional` type class, so the `/` operator doesn't work on `Int`s.

The reason is that regular mathematical division **doesn't** work on integers with this type; `3 / 2` would have to either give `1.5`, in which case it doesn't fit the type `Int -> Int -> Int`, or give `1` or `2`, in which case it wouldn't be correct mathematical division. There is a function `div` for implementing [integer division](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3adiv), usable like `` a `div` b `` in infix notation.

```
-- Couldn't match expected type `Exp' with actual type `Value'
```

This message is about your own types, in a single expression you wrote. And the actual full error message would have given you more context about which part of the expression contains the error. Just follow it through from the top down, checking the types of things yourself and the error very quickly leaps out at you.

In this case, you get to here:

```
Let [("x", (Literal (Number 2)))] (prim Add [(Variable "x"), (Variable "y")])
```

`Let` needs two arguments, a `[(String, Exp)]` and an `Exp`. The list is fine, but the second argument is `(prim Add [(Variable "x"), (Variable "y")])`. Without even digging into the substructure of that to see if it's correct, `prim` has type `Op -> [Value] -> Value`, so there's no way it's going to give you an `Exp`.

How to fix that is up to you; it looks like you need a bit of a refactor across the whole expression/value distinction. `prim` gives you an `Value`, which you could simply apply wrap in a `Literal` to get you past the type error you're getting, but then you run into the problem that `prim` should be taking an `Op` and a `[Value]`, but you appear to have given it an `Op` and a `[Exp]` (containing variables). I think you need to think about the difference between using `prim` to compute the results of a primitive application, using the `Primitive` constructor of `Exp` to *represent* a primitive application, and using `eval` to evaluate (in an environment) an arbitrary expression (which may contain several primitive applications) to a value.

Comment: I am sorry, but what does this "(/) :: Fractional a => a -> a -> a" mean? It means it takes a and another a as parameters and returns a, right? but what does a mean? How am I to know the fact that Int isn't a member of the Fractional type class from that?

Comment: Paul gave you some good information on that already in his answer, but since you're starting from the error message `No instance for (Fractional Int)` GHC has already told you that `Int` isn't a member of `Fractional`.

Comment: @dockbudu I added a little more to my answer about the `Fractional a => a -> a -> a` type, hope it helps.

Comment: @ Ben oh, wow. Your explanation makes it so clear. It definitely helps. Thank you. I now need to go ahead and solve the other one. Thank you so much.

Comment: I tried to resolve the second error and achieve the intended functionality, but couldn't do it completely because there is fundamentally wrong with the declared type system. The core of the problem is that `prim` returns a `Value` but `Let` expects `Exp`. Hence, I'm only able to remove the compile error by declaring as thus: `let t = eval [("y",(Number 40))] (Let [("x",(Literal (Number 2)))] (Literal ((prim Add [Number 2,Number 5]))))`. That is, I converted the value to become `Exp` but putting `Literal`. I also used direct values because the whole thing cannot read the `x` nor the `y`.

Answer (score 30):

The problem you're having is that Haskell has different functions for integer and 'fractional' division. Integer division truncates, fractional division does not. So instead of

```
prim Div [Number a, Number b] = Number (a / b)
```

you want to do

```
prim Div [Number a, Number b] = Number (a `div` b)
```

What the error message actually means is that the function `(/)` is part of the `Fractional` class. This is basically an interface that different types can implement. To get information on it fire up ghci and do

```
Prelude> :i (/)
class Num a => Fractional a where
(/) :: a -> a -> a
...
-- Defined in `GHC.Real'
infixl 7 /

Prelude> :i Int
data Int = GHC.Types.I# GHC.Prim.Int#   -- Defined in `GHC.Types'
instance Bounded Int -- Defined in `GHC.Enum'
instance Enum Int -- Defined in `GHC.Enum'
instance Eq Int -- Defined in `GHC.Classes'
instance Integral Int -- Defined in `GHC.Real'
instance Num Int -- Defined in `GHC.Num'
instance Ord Int -- Defined in `GHC.Classes'
instance Read Int -- Defined in `GHC.Read'
instance Real Int -- Defined in `GHC.Real'
instance Show Int -- Defined in `GHC.Show'
```

The first gives you information about the function `(/)`: it tells you that it is in the class `Fractional`. Then when you `:i Int` it shows you all the instances for `Int`. Notice that `Int` is not an instance of `Fractional` so you can't use `(/)` with `Int`.

Another tip: The backticks (`) turn a function into an infix operator so

```
a `div` b
```

is the same as

```
div a b
```

Comment: Thank you very much, do you have an idea for the second error?

Comment: `div` operator woks for me