# Instance of Fractional Int required for definition

Tags: haskell

```
time :: Int -> (Int,Int,Int)
time x = ((x/3600),(x`mod`3600)/60,((x`mod`3600)`mod`60))
```

Instance of Fractional Int required for definition of time

expample =

time x = (hours, minutes, seconds)

time 3600 = (1,0,0)

given a time in seconds, must show it like this (hours, minutes, seconds) in the example 3600 is 1h 0m 0s

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: given a time in seconds, must show it like this (hours, minutes, seconds) in the example 3600 is 1h 0m 0s

Comment: possible duplicate of [No instance for (Fractional Int) arising from a use of \`/'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14656762/no-instance-for-fractional-int-arising-from-a-use-of)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you are getting that error because you are using the `/` operator with `Int` arguments. You can use `div` to get rid of the error, like so:

```
time :: Int -> (Int,Int,Int)
time x = ((x `div` 3600),(x `mod` 3600) `div` 60,((x `mod` 3600) `mod` 60))
```

As others have pointed out, `(/)` requires arguments to be `Fractional` whereas `div` is happy with `Integral` values.

Answer (score 4):

You can't use the normal division operator on integers.  This is true in mathematics and in Haskell, because division only works when the mathematical structure is a [Field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_%28mathematics%29#Examples).  The integers do not have division defined, but you can perform something similar called *integer division* (yes, a misleading name) or *truncated division*.  This is achieved in Haskell using the `div` function, and you can use it as:

```
time :: Int -> (Int, Int, Int)
time x = (x `div` 3600, (x `mod` 3600) `div` 60, (x `mod` 3600) `mod` 60)
```

Here I've simply replaced each instance of `/` with `div` in its infix form, with no change to your algorithm otherwise.

---

So what does it mean for a type to implement the `/` operator?  If we load up GHCi:

```
> :info (/)
class Num a => Fractional a where
    (/) :: a -> a -> a
    ...
        -- Defined in 'GHC.Real'
infixl 7 /
```

This tells us that `/` is a member of the `Fractional` typeclass, and anything that implements it must also implement the `Num` typeclass.  Put simply, things that can be divided have to be fractional numbers.  What else is in the `Fractional` typeclass?

```
> :info Fractional
class Num a => Fractional a where
    (/) :: a -> a -> a
    recip :: a -> a
    fromRational :: Rational -> a
instance Fractional Float
instance Fractional Double
```

So `Fractional` numbers have division, a reciprocal operation, and a conversion from a `Rational` number.  Ideally, `a * recip a == a / a == 1`, since this is true of our familiar fractional sets (rationals, reals, complex numbers).

Answer (score 3):

The reason it's showing you the error is because `(/)` has the following type:

```
λ> :t (/)
(/) :: Fractional a => a -> a -> a
```

So, it accepts and returns only fractional numbers such as Float and Double. One way of solving this problem would be by using `div` function which has a type of `div :: Integral a => a -> a -> a`.

```
time x = ((x `div` 3600),(x`mod`3600) `div` 60,((x`mod`3600)`mod`60))
```

Another way to solve this problem would be to use the `fromIntegral` function on the number which will be applied to the `/` function and do the proper type conversion while returning:

```
time :: Int -> (Int, Int, Int)
time x = (a,b,c)
  where a = ci $ fi x / fi 3600
        b = ci $ fi (x `mod` 3600) / fi 60
        c = (x `mod` 3600) `mod` 60
        fi = fromIntegral
        ci = ceiling
```