# • No instance for (Fractional Int) arising from a use of ‘/’

Tags: haskell

```
test :: Int -> Int -> Int
test x y = x/y
main = print(test 20 20)
```

error:

```
main.hs:2:12: error:
    • No instance for (Fractional Int) arising from a use of ‘/’
    • In the expression: x / y
      In an equation for ‘test’: test x y = x / y
```

Please help me would appreciate im a beginner in haskell and wanting to learn it even tho that i dont know where can i use it and how can i implement it somewhere, i already know javascript, java, php and lua somewhat but im the best at javascript and lua, would also like if you could answer me where can i implement haskell and how can i put it to good use, thanks :)
P.S. I checked some posts like this already but i didn't really find them helpful, i need a simpler explanation, thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No instance for (Fractional Int) arising from a use of \`/'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14656762/no-instance-for-fractional-int-arising-from-a-use-of)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not divide two `Int` numbers with [**`(/) :: Fractional a => a -> a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-47-). As the type signature indicates, this is used for *fractional* numbers. An `Int` is *not* a `Fractional` number, but an `Integral` number.

You can make use of [**`div :: Integral a => a -> a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:div) or [**`quot :: Integral a => a -> a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:quot) instead:

```
test :: Int -> Int -> Int
test = div
```

It however is not necessary to here write `test = div`, you can use `div` directly.

The functions `div` and `quot` are not equivalent. `quot` is truncated towards zero, whereas `div` is truncated towards negative infinity. If you divide by positive numbers, then this does not matter, but if the numerator, or the denominator is negative, then this can give different results. For example:

```
Prelude> div 5 (-2)
-3
Prelude> quot 5 (-2)
-2
```

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: Hey, actually i would appreciate if you could write me an example of how my code could work that would help me a lot actually cause im still confused

Comment: `main = print (div 20 20)`?

Comment: Ohhh thanks im really dumb sorry about this i appreciate your help

Comment: Hey, might i ask, how can i divide like 1 with 2 and get the result 0.5

Comment: @GamzXT: then you need to convert the numbers to a `Fractional` type. For example `toFracDiv :: (Integral a, Integral b, Fractional c) => a -> b -> c` and `toFracDiv x y = fromIntegral x / fromIntegral y`.

Comment: Thank you, also last question, any good website where i can find all of those keywords like "fromIntegral"

Comment: @GamzXT: you can make use of *hoogle* to search both on names and signatures: https://hoogle.haskell.org/