# Couldn't match type 'b' with Int

Tags: haskell

Task: Transform a list of numbers using map so every even number gets divided by 2 and every odd number gets multiplied by 2

```
prel2 :: (Fractional b) => [Int] -> [b]
prel2 x = map prel x
     where prel y
        |even y = y/2
        |otherwise = y*2
```

I know this is some basic stuff, but I can't figure out why the error is raised

Comment: I think you want to use the signature `prel2 :: [Int] -> [Int]`. You'll still get an error, but there are answers elsewhere for that, e.g.: [No instance for (Fractional Int) arising from a use of `/'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14656762/15207568).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your type signature promises that you can provide a list of values of any type that has a `Fractional` instance. But, since `y` is *always* an `Int` (since `x :: [Int]`), then `y*2` will always be an `Int`, and `y/2` wouldn't type-check at all.

What you *probably* want is to use `div` instead of `/` to replace the `Fractional` constraint with an `Integral` constraint, then generalize your type to `Integral b => [b] -> [b]`.